# Clion потребляет много оперативки

Tags: c++, память, clion, ram

Clion потребляет 2500мб в работе, при этом проекты не большие, это несмотря даже на подключенные либы. Работал с sfml, и просто запускал в новом проекте Hello World в консоли, потребление одинаковое 1900 - 2500 мб. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Ну и пусть потребляет.  Нужно угадать почему?...

Comment: Это прям мизерное потребление. На нормальных проектах он легко больще 16 съедает. Это же java. Если используете Windows, то используйте Visual Studio.